Randomly permuted range iterator in c++
I wish to iterate over a "range" {0...n} in a random order.
I have an iterator for the range {0..n}:
class range
{
private:
    int last;
    int iter;

public:
    range(int end):
        last(end),
        iter(0)
    {}

    // Iterable functions
    const range& begin() const { return *this; }
    const range& end() const { return *this; }

    // Iterator functions
    bool operator!=(const range&) const { return iter < last; }
    bool operator==(const range&) const { return iter == last; }
    void operator++() { ++iter; }
    int operator*() const { return iter; }
};

And I wish to use shuffle to create a random permutation of it, which I can then use in a for loop:
range ob_range = range(n_objects);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0, 10000);
std::shuffle(ob_range.begin(), ob_range.end(), distr);

for (int i : ob_range)
{

However I am getting an error message which is beyond me to decrypt:

no type named ‘difference_type’ in ‘struct
std::iterator_traits’

How can I fix my code?
(Please note that I tried using this, which I found in a code snippet:
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
std::shuffle(ob_range.begin(), ob_range.end(), g);

But I was informed that "error: ‘random_device’ is not a member of ‘std’")

Did you #include <random> when you used std::random_device?

[mcve] - did you e.g. include <random> header? I suppose you use C++11 or newer?

Please try to create a single coherent [mre]. And please tell us the actual problem that your range class solve that can't be solved by other standard library classes or functions.

Compilation error aside, your class range doesn't make much sense, it certainly doesn't model a range. Your begin end methods are returning class range which doesn't satisfy RandomAccessIterator, so you cannot std::shuffle(ob_range.begin() .... Your comparison operators don't even compare the correct objects.

Is there a functioning std:: iterator which would suffice as opposed to my apparently broken "range"?  This is for being able to do:
for (int i : range(10))

is there any reason to write a custom range or iterators you are not already mentioning? Because this can be a whole lot simpler, just iota your unshuffled "range" of indices into a std::vector<size_t>, shuffle it, done.

"But I was informed that "error: ‘random_device’ is not a member of ‘std’"" thats due to a missing header or similar issue. Generally you should post a [mcve] alongside with the complete compiler error message

begin() which do return *this; this seems wrong.

Based on this I have done this, which works, thank you:
std::vector shuffled_object_ids(n_objects);
std::iota(shuffled_object_ids.begin(), shuffled_object_ids.end(), 0);
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
std::shuffle(shuffled_object_ids.begin(), shuffled_object_ids.end(), g);


If you have solved it, you can post an answer and get more suggestions from others. Make sure your answer is complete and not code-only.

@Omroth please any new information add directly to question by [edit]. It should be possible to answer question without reading comments.

You can't std::shuffle a range that lazily generates values, as it has to swap the results of operator*. You will need to fill some container with those values, and then shuffle that container.
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

constexpr int n_objects = 10;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> ob_range(n_objects);
    std::iota(ob_range.begin(), ob_range.end(), 0);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::shuffle(ob_range.begin(), ob_range.end(), rd);

    for (int i : ob_range)
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}

See it on godbolt

Note that for some use cases, you can generate a permutation of the first 2^n integers without the need to hold the integers in some container, ie. the integers are computed on the fly. For instance, Linear feedback shift register allows this; however, I guess that the statistical properties of an integer sequence generated like this are far from those of a "true" random generator.

@edrezen perhaps, but you can't do that with std::shuffle. It explicitly needs to std::iter_swap pairs of iterators

It appears based on comments that my range iterator is pretty janky and not fit for purpose.  For now I've implemented the following, which works:
std::vector<int> shuffled_object_ids(n_objects);
for (int index = 0; index < n_objects; index += 1)
{
   shuffled_object_ids[index] = index;
}
    
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
std::shuffle(shuffled_object_ids.begin(), shuffled_object_ids.end(), g);


I'm not very comfortable with iterators and I got some strange results from using iota

That's basically how to shuffle a vector of ints. You didn't see this topic while googling how to solve the problem?

And how does this answer fix the error: ‘random_device’ is not a member of ‘std' problem you had?
